# Phonegap app layout size type

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm developing an app for iOS devices using Phonegap (Cordova). I'm a little confused on how to define object sizes in html since different devices have different pixel densities.

Should I specify dimensions in percentages or pixels? And what should be the referent size?

This also referee to image sizes.

Should I grab a screen size at the begging and modify object sizes in javascript according to these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea is to use dppx unit (number of dots per px unit). This number is pretty constant across mobile devices...

For more info visit the [link](http://Number%20of%20dots%20per%20px%20unit).